# Can't get effect working in ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

I must confess the intricate workings of ControlTemplates is not something I'm prepared to write books about quite yet. :O)

Anyway, I've written a custom button (there must be thosuands out there) to fit the needs of the HMI (Human Machine Interface) of a customer and a of course I've provided a ControlTemplate for it.

The button always display a black drop shadow but now I want the shadow it to change color when the button gets "hot", as in when the mouse is hovering over it (the button class - `HmiToolbarButton` - supports a d-property called "`IsHot`").

Here's the (non working) template:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:HmiToolbarButton}">
    <Setter Property="AutoSize" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="HotBehaviorNormal" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:HmiToolbarButton}">
                <Grid x:Name="_grd">
                    <Border 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        >
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_CONTENT" />
                    </Border>
                    <local:ButtonHotDecorator IsHitTestVisible="False" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}" IsMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsHot}" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding HotBehaviorNormal}" />
                    <Grid.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Opacity="0.9" BlurRadius="10" Color="{TemplateBinding DropShadowColor}" />
                    </Grid.Effect>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsHot" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="_grd" Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <!-- *** PROBLEM HERE *** -->
                                <DropShadowEffect 
                                    ShadowDepth="0" Opacity="0.9" BlurRadius="10" 
                                    Color="{TemplateBinding HotDropShadowColor}" 
                                    />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The black drop shadow works ok but I get no effect at all when I move the mouse over the button. I suspect it's the `TemplateBinding` that's not working because if I change it to a constant color the effect displays as expected.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes TemplateBinding has trouble resolving when it's not located directly inside the template itself. Here you're using it in a new object instantiation inside a Setter inside a Trigger, so that's probably what the problem is. Try using RelativeSource instead for the one in the Trigger:

```
<DropShadowEffect 
  ShadowDepth="0" Opacity="0.9" BlurRadius="10" 
  Color="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=HotDropShadowColor}" 
  />
```

Comment: Thanks John, that was it. I realize I need to read up on templates but I've found it difficult to find good and exhaustive documentation anywhere. Can you recommend one or two resources. It would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: WPF Control Development Unleashed has decent coverage of just about everything related to controls but I think is missing some of the newer stuff like VisualStateManager and behaviors.